# RegExp in Python

Tags: python, regex

This is an example that searches PDF files in the current directory.

```
import os, os.path
import re

def print_pdf (arg, dir, files):
 for file in files:
  path = os.path.join(dir, file)
  path = os.path.normcase(path)
  if re.search(r".*\.pdf", path):
   print path

os.path.walk('.', print_pdf, 0)
```

Could anyone explain what `r".*\.pdf"` means here?

Why `".*\"`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why `".*\"`?

Wrong question, you missed a crucial character of the expression. ;-)

In fact, `.*` will match *any* character (`.` in regex), *as many times as possible* (`*` in regex; relates to the previous string, so `.` in this case).

`\.`, on the other hand, will match exactly one dot (`.`). `\` escapes the following character (`.`) so it does no longer have its special meaning (e.g. in this case “match *any* character”) but rather it will be treated as-is.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! also thanks to SilentGhost, but I can  only choose one answer. :)

Answer (score 8):

it means any character zero or more times, followed by the literal dot and letters pdf (due to the greedy nature of the asterisk, it's basically guaranteed that the `'.pdf'` are going to be at the end of the subject string).

There is [`glob`](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html) module to do this the right way:

```
>>> glob.glob(os.path.join(dirname, '*.pdf'))
```

Comment: Or at least get rid of the regex with `path.endswith('.pdf')`

Answer (score 2):

The `.` means match any character but "\n". The `*` means "repeat the previous character 0 or more times". The `\.` matches an actual ".".

BTW, this is all in [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html).

Answer (score 1):

This searches for a string containing zero or more chars followed by ".pdf"  The .* is a common idiom in regexps and it means match any char 0 or more times.  The . is because in regexps, the . has a special meaning, and the \ escapes that.

Answer (score 0):

**The period (.)**
will match any character except newlines

**The following asterisk (*)**
   means unlimited number of repetitions
   of the preceding period

**The backslash ()**
escapes the period in .pdf So it looks for a real
   period, so ONLY the .pdf and not "any
   character".pdf again'

So in the end it looks for
Any piece of text that ends in .pdf

Answer (score 0):

use [os.walk()](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html) instead. And there's no need to use regex.

```
for r,d,f in os.walk(path):
    for files in f:
        if files[-4:].lower() == ".pdf":
             print "found pdf: ",os.path.join(r,files)
```